# Saving data in myql and sending mail to the subscriber. How to Resolve it?

Tags: php, mailchimp

Data is Saving in the `mysql` database but `mailchimp` shows this error.

Actually I am saving the form data firstly in the database and than to the list of the mailchimp. everything working well but the following error is not resolved no data saved in the list.

```
string(270) "{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
"title":"Bad Request",
"status":400,
"detail":"We couldn\u2019t find the email address you provided on the list for this automation.",
"instance":"4b159025-b363-4306-bb3b-58159b6e1d02"}
```

Comment: Set Your Keys and merge tags correctly.

Comment: all are setup everything is fine

Comment: So than wait for the answer someone will answer.

Comment: ok thanks for appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact their Developers and use contact forum You will get the solution by them may be your account is not supporting their terms and conditions.

Comment: thats great happy coding.